# How to save offline data in device storage in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing an app that simple guess game, I wan to store how many time  they guess or how many time they tried and show it to gameboard, how do I track and store the data to phone storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your problem [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) is the package that you may want to use. However this stores data but is not reactive(i.e. changes cannot be seen immediately using streams). For that you may want to use [streaming_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/streaming_shared_preferences) or [rx_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/rx_shared_preferences). Either of them should work fine and using them you get all features of shared preferences plus the reactive feature.